Almost never events of XOR-Gate
Given a XOR-Gate, two inputs $X_1$ and $X_2$ and an output Y. Each variable is either 1 or zero, with equal probability.
I wonder if $X_1 = 1$, $X_2=1$, $Y=1$ is never or almost never going to happen in the sense of probability theory.
In the light of this a follow up question:
How does the sample space of the joint probability distribution $p(X_1, X_2, Y)$ look?
Is it $\chi_1 \times \chi_2 \times \mathbb{Y}$  with, e.g. $p(X_1 = 1$, $X_2=1$, $Y=1) = 0$ or is this wrong?

After a number of considerations I came to the following conclusion:
$X_1=X_2=Y=1$ is never going to happen, this just follows from the definition of the XOR-Gate. Hence, it is not a possible outcome, it is impossible, and not just almost impossible. Meaning you cannot assign a probability (p=0) to it, because its not a valid element of the sample space.
Hence the sample space does not contain $X_1=X_2=Y=1$.
Otherwise $p(X_1=X_2=Y=1) = 0$ would be a null-set in the measure theoretic sense. Elements of the null-set are not necessarily impossible to happen. $X_1=X_2=Y=1$, however, is. For a consistent definition, $X_1=X_2=Y=1$ cannot be an element of the null-space.

$X_1=X_2=Y=1$ would never ever happen, simply because $Y$ is defined as $X_1 \oplus X_2$, and so if $X_1 = X_2 = 1$ then it is guaranteed that $Y = 1 \oplus 1 = 0$. So $\Pr(X_1=X_2=Y=1) = 0$.
The probability distribution of $(X_1,X_2,Y)$ would give $1/4$ probability to the following tuples: $(0,0,0), (0,1,1), (1,0,1), (1,1,0)$ and $0$ probability to the other four tuples.

Yeah, but why can you simply assign probability zero to an event that is not even contained in the sample space? If $X_1=1 = X_2 = Y = 1$ is in the sample space, it is almost never going to happen and you can assign probability 0 to it like you did. But this is paradox as $X_1 \oplus X_2$ never admits $Y =1$ as you correctly noted and therefore, it doesnt just happen almost never, but never. Otherwise it is not in the sample space, but then you  cannot assign probability zero to it.

@PhilGer It is true that $(1,1,1)$ is not an outcome in the sample space. However, as random variables over the sample space, it is still meaningful to say $\Pr(X_1=X_2=Y=1) = 0$.

can you give me source for this statement? This is the very thing I am not really sure about: if one can assign a probability to an event which is not contained in the sample space of the joint distribution.
